# C++ won't let me compare pointer and int

Tags: c++, string

So I'm learning C++ and I'm trying to learn how to manipulate strings and such, in this code segment, I am looking to present a particular string with no spaces:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string intro = "Hello my name is John";
    for(string::iterator it = intro.begin(); it != intro.end(); ++it) {
        if((*it) != " ") {
            cout << *it;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm completely oblivious to what I'm doing wrong here. Can anyone help? I haven't used any integers and the error says "ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and int"

Comment: This isn't the problem, but you don't need the parentheses around `*it` in the `if` statement.

Comment: @Nightcrawler And this is the comments section

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that `" "` (double quotes) is not a single space character. It is a string literal that consists of a space character and a null terminator.

The type of a string literal is `const char[]`, which decays into a `const char*` for the comparison. A single `char`, on the other hand, is a numeric type, which gets promoted to an `int` for comparison. This is the reason the compiler tells you that you are trying to compare a pointer to an int.

You need to replace `" "` with `' '` (single quotes), which is a single `char`, in order for your program to compile.

Comment: No, this string literal has type `const char[2]`.

Comment: Which in fact degenerate to ```const char *``` in many situations.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to compare a single character to a whole string of characters.

I assume you want to only compare the character given by `*it` to a single character, the space? Then you should instead do `*it == ' '`. Note the use of *single* quotes, to denote a character literal.

---

As for the "integer" thing, in arithmetic expressions (which comparison is) the compiler converts types smaller than `int` to an `int`, so a character type `char` is automatically converted to an `int` with the same value, and then you use that `int` value in the comparison with the pointer given by the string literal `" "`.

Answer (score 4):

`*it` will return the element of the `std::string`, i.e. a `char`, and `" "` is a [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) with type `const char[2]` (the space and the null character), it might decay to `const char*`, i.e. a pointer. Their types don't match.

You should change

```
if((*it) != " ") {
```

to

```
if((*it) != ' ') {
```

it works because `' '` is a char too.

Answer (score 0):

A short answer.

`*it` is a `char` (*small integer*) since you're iterating a `std::string` which is a sequence of `char`.

And `" "` is a `const char *` (a space character followed by NULL terminator).

So you are comparing an integer to a pointer here:

```
if((*it) != " ") {
```

Which is the reason for:

> "ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and int"

Replace `" "` with the `char` `' '`, which is (*small integer*) 32.

By *small integer* I mean something like `int8_t`, an 8 bit integer. It varies.